# algebraic geometry and variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question is: why dimension of variety is well defined? I mean, if $K$ is an algebraically closed field and $V$ is a variety on $K$, why is the extension $K(V)$ (the rational functions field of $V$) of $K$ a finitely generated extension?

Thanks.

Comment: You have asked this question 3 times already. Please stop doing this, we don't like it here. If you really don't get an answer to a question, then that's it, don't be pushy.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V\subseteq\mathbf{A}^n$ be an affine variety with affine coordinate ring $A(V)$ then the function field $K(V)$ is isomorphic to the quotient field of $A(V)$, hence it is a finitely generated extension field of $k$ (of transcendence degree $dim\,V$, the dimension of $V$ as a topological space for the topology induced by the Zarisky topology). Indeed, $A(V)$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra.

Some additional explanations. Recall that the quotient field of $A(V)$ is the localization $S^{-1}A(V)$, where $S$ is the multiplicative set consisting in all non-zero elements of $A(V)$. One has a ring-homomorphism from $A(V)$ to $S^{-1}A(V)$, which maps an element $f$ to $f/1$. Now, recall the definition of $A(V):= k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I(V)$, where $I(V)$ is the ideal associated with $V$, namely $I(V):=\lbrace f\in k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]|\; f(P)= 0\;\text{for all point P of V}\rbrace$, and let $i$ denotes the inclusion of $k$ into $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ and $p$ from $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ to $A(V)$ denotes the canonical morphism. The fact that $A(V)$ is finitely generated means it is finitely generated as a ring over $p(i(k))$, i.e $A(V) = p(i(k))[T]$ for $T$ a finite subset of $A(V)$ whose elements $t_1,\ldots,t_m$ are called the ring generators. Then one should be able to check that $t_1/1,\dots,t_m/1,1/t_1,\ldots,1/t_m$ is a basis for $S^{-1}A(V)$ as a $k$-vector space. One concludes that $S^{-1}A(V)=k(t_1/1,\ldots,t_m/1,1/t_1,\ldots,1/t_m)$.

Comment: why "hence" it is finitely generated? thanks

Comment: @user371596: I edited my answer. If needed I will add some details in a couple of hours when I will have some free time.